# How to convert test operator from bash to sh?

Tags: bash, sh

I have next string comparison in `bash`:

```
if [[ $1 == "/"* ]]; then echo YES; else echo "$1"; fi
```

How to do same in `sh`?

Comment: @tripleee: fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a `case` statement.

```
case $1 in
    /*) echo YES;;
    *)  echo $1
esac
```

The direct translation would be `if [ "$1" = "/*" ]`, but it wouldn't work because sh doesn't support glob matches there. You'd need to invoke an external command like `grep`.

```
if printf '%s\n' "$1" | grep -e '^/' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    ...
fi
```

This would be shorter with `grep -q`, but if you don't have bash then you may not have `grep -q` either.

Comment: IMO, we should be able to assume POSIX-compliant tools (`-q` is specified by POSIX), and let the OP ask about non-compliant tools.

Comment: `expr "$1" : '/.*'` would be a POSIX-compliant alternative to piping the value into `grep` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `case` statement handles this elegantly.

```
case $1 in 
 '/'* ) echo YES;;
 *) echo "$1";;
esac
```

The lack of quoting before `in` and the general syntax with the double semicolons and unpaired right parentheses is jarring to the newcomer, but you quickly get used to it.  It's quite versatile and much under-appreciated.

If you insist on using `[` you could perhaps do something like

```
if temp=${1#?}; [ "${1%$temp}" -eq '*' ]; then
    ...
```

which uses a couple of parameter expansions to extract the first character of the variable; but `case` has glob pattern matching built in, so it's considerably more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to match a pattern, or regex in `if` statements if `sh` or `fish` you can use

```
if echo "$1" | grep -q ^/; then echo yes; else echo "$1"; fi
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing up the syntax of `csh` with the syntax of `sh`. They are two different languages.

Comment: @triplee, what do you mean, I'm a bit puzzled by your comment? pattern matching in `sh` does not work, so you can use `grep`. Where do you see the `csh`?

Comment: In `sh` the parentheses around `echo $1 | grep` create a subshell which is unnecessary and inefficient here.  In `csh` you actually use parentheses in this position, but here, `if echo $1 | grep -Eq "/.*"` would work as well ... or actually, as badly; you still have a quoting error and an unnecessary `-E` and the wrong regex (but try `if echo "$1" | grep -q '^/'; then` if you insist on using an external process for something the shell can do without an external process).

Comment: @tripleee, I have checked what you said ... and surprise ... you are correct ;). I have done the update as you suggested. I do agree that this solution is not really that nice, but if you need the `if` statement, then this has a good readability. Nonetheless, the `case` solution is eleganter.

Comment: @triplee and just fixed the quoting again.